# End Program After MessageBox is Closed

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

At the very beginning of my program, I am checking to see if I can initiate a connection with a device on COM6. If the device is not found, then I want to display a MessageBox and then completely end the program.

Here's what I have so far in the `Main()` function of the initial program:

```
try
{
    reader = new Reader("COM6");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Device Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
}

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

When I try putting a `Application.Exit();` after the MessageBox command, the MessageBox displays correctly when no device is detected, but when I close the MessageBox, Form1 still opens, but is completely frozen and won't let me close it or click any of the buttons that should give me an error anyways since the device is not connected.

I am just looking for away to kill the program completely after the MessageBox is displayed. Thanks.

**SOLUTION:** After using the `return;` method after the MessageBox closed the program quit just as I wanted when the device was not plugged it. However, when the device was plugged in, it still had issues reading after to test. This was something I hadn't discovered before, but it was a simple fix. Here is my fully working code:

```
try
{
    test = new Reader("COM6");
    test.Dispose(); //Had to dispose so that I could connect later in the program. Simple fix.
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No device was detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    return;
}
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is in the `Main()` routine, just return:

```
try
{
    reader = new Reader("COM6");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Device Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    return; // Will exit the program
}

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
//... Other code here..
```

Returning from `Main()` will exit the process.

Comment: That was simple. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: This answer should add more explanation about why `Application.Exit()` didn't work as explained by `Jan Doerrenhaus`

Answer (score 7):

`Application.Exit` tells your WinForms application to stop the message pump, therefore exiting the program. If you call it before you call `Application.Run`, the message pump never got to start in the first place, so it freezes.

If you want to terminate your program, no matter what state it is in, use `Environment.Exit`.

Comment: Probably not what I need here, but this is useful to know for future issues I may have. I've been looking for that "kill-all" sort of code.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `boolean` to the top to determine if the operation completed.

```
bool readerCompleted = false;
try
{
    reader = new Reader("COM6");
    readerCompleted = true;
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Device Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
}

if(readerCompleted)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Because there is no code after the `if` statement, the program will just close when the boolean is false.

You can apply this sort of logic to any other section of your code, not just the `Main()` function.

Comment: This worked for what I originally wanted, but now the program wont work when the device is plugged in. I'm going to play with this for a little bit, but thanks for helping me fix the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Application.Exit() after your message box code
 `catch

{

MessageBox.Show("No Device Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error")

Application.Exit();

}`